# SQL Server - sum a column using group by

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have columns in the below format
[image]

and I am looking for an output by adding the last column based on the first column
[image]
Please could you someone suggest the best approach?

Best regards

Comment: Do you have an auto-incrementing ID column in the table?

Comment: well it can be any number higher than the previous value. won't run the order though.

Comment: You could use `OVER(PARTITION BY...`, but this would give you a value for `NewField` that's the same for every row with the same `wouid`

Comment: Look at [RollUp](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522495(v=sql.105).aspx).

Comment: Thanks "Lamak" worked for me, not as expected but can manage from here.

Comment: If you have received your answer, you may choose to remove your question or answer your own question and mark it accepted (or mark a different answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

used Over(Partition by.....)
in the following way and it worked

,Sum(NewBill) OVER (PARTITION BY wouid) AS Newfield

Thanks for all your support guys.